# How to render a razor page instead of static html content without redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, razor-pages

In old ASP.NET WebForms I used

```
HttpApplication.Context.RewritePath
```

method in Global.asax to rewrite url - redirect without actually changing URL displayed in the browser.

Now I use following code in ASP.NET Core 3.0 to redirect some static content to a razor page:

```
public class RedirectHtmlRequests : IRule
{
    private readonly string _docPath;
    private readonly string _fldPublic;
    private readonly string _fldPrivate;

    public RedirectHtmlRequests(string docPath, string fldPublic, string fldPrivate)
    {
        this._docPath = docPath.ToLower();
        this._fldPublic = fldPublic.ToLower();
        this._fldPrivate = fldPrivate.ToLower();
    }

    public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {            
        var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

        if (request.Path.Value.EndsWith(".htm", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
            || request.Path.Value.EndsWith(".html", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            //response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status301MovedPermanently;
            //context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
            int id = FindDocumentByUri(request.Path);
            if (id > 0)
            {
                //context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(string.Format("/Dokument/{0}", id));
                var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
                response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
                context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
                response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = (string.Format("/Dokument/{0}", id));
            }
        }
    }
```

Startup.cs

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().Add(new RedirectHtmlRequests("Dokumenty/", "Verejne/", "Duverne/")));
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(env?.ContentRootPath).FullName, "Dokumenty")),
    RequestPath = "/Dokumenty"
});
```

But the line

```
response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = (string.Format("/Dokument/{0}", id));
```

actually redirects the url in the browser window to `/Dokument/{ID}`, and that is not desirable. What command should I use instead?

Comment: A point in terms of terminology - a redirect will **by definition** impact the URL in the browser. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections I suspect what you want to do is render a given page for a given URL (which is more of a _routing_ concern).

Comment: Yes, I want to render that razor page instead of html content.

Comment: But in WebForms it worked using `HttpApplication.Context.RewritePath`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing `HttpContext.Request.Path` with a route to a razor page did the trick for me:

```
if (id > 0)
{
    context.HttpContext.Request.Path = (string.Format("/Dokument/{0}", id));
    context.Result = RuleResult.SkipRemainingRules;
}
```